# Eulerian connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a question on grap theory as follows

$G=(V,E)$ is a connected graph. Prove that G is Eulerian if and only if there is a partition $E_j$, $j=1,...,m$ of the set of edges such that every $E_j$ is the set of edges of a cycle of $G$.

I would like you to give ideas for solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Sometimes a brief description of what you've tried will help us tailor our responses for you. Anyway have you tried constructing an Eulerian cycle from the cycles? The other direction is obvious by the definition of Eulerian cycle.

Comment: If it is Eulerian the we can construct the partition following an Euler path. Put the first edge to be traveled in $E_1$ and continue doing so with the next ones while you don't return to the same vertex. When you return to the same initial vertex start putting the next edges in a new $E_i$.

Comment: Conversely, assume the partition of the edges exists. Begin from any vertex of an edge in $E_1$, move along that edge. If the new vertex doesn't belong to any $E_i$, with greater $i$, continue along the cycle corresponding to $E_1$, if the vertex does belong to another $E_i$ continue along an edge of $E_i$ that contains that vertex. Repeat the same process for $E_i$. We change to the first $E_j$ with $j>i$ that also contains an edge to the vertex we just moved using the edge from $E_i$. This produces an Euler circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that if every vertex had degree at least $2$, then there exists a cycle.

There is another fact you should be using- if every vertex in a graph has an even degree, then the graph has a decomposition into edge-disjoint cycles. The proof sketch for this is as follows. Take a maximial list of edge-disjoint cycles within the graph $G$. Suppose every vertex in $G$ has an even degree. Now remove all the edges of these cycles from $G$, and suppose $G$ still contains an edge. This implies at least one vertex in $G$ has odd degree, a contradiction.

So if $G$ is Eulerian, every vertex has even degree, and so the forward side follows trivially.

Now for the converse, suppose $G$ has a decomposition into edge disjoint cycles but not every vertex is even. Then you have a contradiction based on the second fact I stated above.